# Check DTS Package Info

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-package

In SQL Server 2005, I would check the version of my package like so:

```
USE [msdb]
GO
SELECT [Name], CAST([VerMajor] AS VARCHAR(4)) + '.' + CAST([VerMinor] AS VARCHAR(4)) + '.' + CAST([VerBuild] AS VARCHAR(4)) 
AS [Version]
FROM [dbo].[sysdtspackages90]
WHERE [Name] IN ('MYPackage')
Order by [Name]
```

In SQL Server 2008 - I do not see the table `[dbo].[sysdtspackages90]`.

If I replace the table with `[dbo].[sysdtspackages]` in my query, I get back 0 rows.

Where is the package information stored in 2008? Or am I not seeing any record returned by `Select * from [dbo].[sysdtspackages]` because I do not have the right permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM msdb..sysssispackages
```

Here's the docs on [SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181582%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

> Contains one row for each package that
>   is saved to Microsoft SQL Server. *This
>   table is stored in the **msdb** database.*

Comment: Thank you, that works. However I killed the query after 2 minutes as it was still not done, but still returned the info I needed. What does ".." mean? Care to explain your answer?

Comment: One more doubt... "2009-12-29 09:08:07.000" was the createdate for one of my packages. This particular package was (maybe) initially created by me in 2009 - in 2005. This was then converted to 2008 in (maybe around) Dec 2010 and then saved to SQL Server in the last few days. The creation date seems very irrelevant - a modified date / install date would have been more helpful. do you know if it is saved somewhere else? Thank you so much for the info...

Comment: @Needs Help: the `msdb..sysssispackages` just means: inside the `msdb` database, and inside the default schema, find the `sysssispackages` catalog view. You could also write `msdb.dbo.sysssispackages` if you like. And sorry - this is the *only* catalog view I know that has this kind of info - if what you're looking for is not there, it's probably not stored anywhere...